# Android view change onComplete

Tags: android, animation, android-lifecycle

I have a card game that uses a programatically set **GridView** with a custom **ArrayAdapter** hooked to an array of 'cards' to animate flipping the cards upon dealing via `getView()`. I need to know when all the cards are done flipping so that the game can deal again or possibly perform another action if it needs to based on the current state of the cards. This has to happen after the last animation of the current flip of course (I already know the state of the cards but I want to deal or other action to happen "in order" after the cards are flipped and before the user can make any changes to the screen). I know that I can count and set a global variable and/or poll for the state but I would prefer to be able to do it the 'correct' way - if there is such a way better than a global count/poll. I can't figure out how better to do it. Suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trace detailed states of the cards through out your game, I would suggest you to set one object for each of the cards.ie

```
public class Card {
    public enum CardState {
        CARD_FACE, CARD_FLIPPING, CARD_BACK
    }
    private CardState cardState;
    //other card object variables

    public Card(){
        cardState = CardState.CARD_BACK;
        //other card object variables default status
    }

    public CardState getCardState() {
        return cardState;
    }

    public void setCardState(CardState cardState) {
        this.cardState = cardState;
    }

    //other getters and setters
}
```

Use an array to store all the card objects in your game controller. By checking the array, you can determine the next action.

Comment: Thanks @VoidExplorer, I think I realized the same thing the more that I thought about it. I was trying to avoid having to poll the state of the cards but since they are animated there isn't really a way around polling huh. Even if there was an onComplete lifecycle event for the ArrayAdapter or the view (there doesn't seem to be) the animations happen on their own threads. I will use your solution thanks!

Comment: If you are really interested in making games, try some game engines, like Unity, LibGDX. They handle many complicated processes for you, for example, animations, input & output, sound effects and etc.